# Is Passing Tenant ID in JWT Token a good practice?

Tags: asp.net-core, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi tenant web app where I will have 1 app and 1 database for all my tenants.

I have been reading about the different techniques to pass the tenant ID from server to client and viceversa for my REST requests/responses and it seems that the one that could fit better for me is passing the tennat id in the JWT Token because I won't have differnt domains for my tenants and passing it in a X-TENANT-ID seems insecure because anyone could change it(Any information on this will be greatly appreciated).

So, is it a good practice to pass the tenant id in the JWT Token? Beside the other alternative (Passing the tenant id in a X-TENANT-ID header) are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: `because anyone could change it` ... _no_ part of the JWT can be tampered with without the server finding out about it.  As to whether your clients can even _see_ the tenant information, that is another story.

Comment: Well, I was refering that it could be changed if ussing X-TENANT-ID header. When making a request from client to server it could be tampered by a malicius user.

Comment: Are you saying some other portion of the header could be altered?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  the OP mentioned two options: including in the JWT or including as a customer HTTP header. OP is correct in stating that JWT cannot be tampered with, but custom HTTP header (X-TENANT-ID) _can_ be tampered with.

Comment: @JasonSmith So, it seems the JWT would be preffered over the HTTP header because of the security reasons or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but if the tenant ID must be exposed, I prefer to put it in the JWT for the same reasons you mentioned. If it's not in the JWT, you have to do some cross-checking to ensure that the current user can access the supplied tenant ID. If each user can only be a member of one tenant, you could skip the tenant ID and derive it from the user ID.

Comment: That was exactly was I was thinking. It seems JWT could be best option in my particular case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm putting it into the JWT token as a claim.

You can also pass it on the URL. If you look at Azure DevOps REST API it has /{organisation}/ in there. You then validate the claim against the URL.

I'm leaning towards doing both. Having it in the URL may help with logging, and also anonymous access if granted.

I'm using Auth0 to generate the tokens and honestly there options for supporting multitenant apps are terrible, and will not scale. To support a user accessing multiple tenants with different permissions is a challenge. If I stick with Auth0 my plan is to generate unique roles per client and assign the user to them, then in the JWT token include the permissions and tenantid. I'll issue a JWT per tenant.